# Email resource file change not applied for additional brand

Tags: docusignapi

The change I am trying to make is to remove the "Conditional:ShowIntroductionSender" block that adds the sender name and email address before the email blurb in every Completed Docusign email that comes to signers after signing.

I was able to remove it for the default brand and it worked without any issues, but when I added an additional brand, the exact same change doesn't seem to be applied in any of our environments.

Is there a known issue, should we use a different approach when modifying resource files for non-default brands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution for us was to download the master resource file, then replace the custom file with the master file, then make the changes in the resource file again and re-upload the modified file. Then it worked!

It was not working when we were simply downloading the master file, making the changes there again and re-uploading. Seems like uploading the master is an important step when trying to reset and re-try making the changes that didn't get applied.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure you change the resource file for each brand that you're using. If a user is not using your default brand, then the default brand's resource file will not be applied.

See branding documentation: https://support.docusign.com/knowledgemarket/article/Best-Practices-Branding-Resource-Files